# BUS_ADRERR in dlopen()

Tags: java, linux, crash, dlopen

What could be causing `BUS_ADRERR` signal during `dlopen()`? I'm receiving many such crash reports from different users.

Some notes:

1. It happens with different libraries (our application uses a few)
2. `si_addr` address of signal points into loaded library. This really puzzles me.
3. There's always enough system memory available.
4. Users say that the application will start correctly on second attempt.
5. Our application extracts the libraries from ZIP before loading them.
6. Studying `journalctl` shows nothing of interest.

Typical crash report (generated by Java):

```
Stack: [0x00007f284919b000,0x00007f284939c000],  sp=0x00007f2849397258,  free space=2032k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0x1fa6f]
C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0x8ffc]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z+0 java.base@10.0.1
j  java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load()Z+53 java.base@10.0.1
j  java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z+216 java.base@10.0.1
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/io/File;)Z+46 java.base@10.0.1
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+48 java.base@10.0.1
j  java.lang.Runtime.load0(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)V+57 java.base@10.0.1
j  java.lang.System.load(Ljava/lang/String;)V+7 java.base@10.0.1
<snip>

siginfo: si_signo: 7 (SIGBUS), si_code: 2 (BUS_ADRERR), si_addr: 0x00007f27deec7880

<snip>

7f27dec43000-7f27decc1000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 1054117 <snip>/libswt-gtk-4922r22.so
7f27decc1000-7f27deec0000 ---p 0007e000 08:08 1054117 <snip>/libswt-gtk-4922r22.so
7f27deec0000-7f27deec8000 rw-p 0007d000 08:08 1054117 <snip>/libswt-gtk-4922r22.so
7f27deec8000-7f27deecb000 r-xp 00285000 08:08 1054117 <snip>/libswt-gtk-4922r22.so

<snip>

Memory: 4k page, physical 3902428k(1540768k free), swap 3998716k(3998716k free)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SIGBUS` is very rare on Linux / x86 systems.

One case where it happens, is when an `mmap`ed file is truncated. From [man mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html):

```
SIGBUS Attempted access to a portion of the buffer that does not
       correspond to the file (for example, beyond the end of the
       file, including the case where another process has truncated
       the file).
```

> Our application extracts the libraries from ZIP before loading them.

A wild guess: you have a race condition, where you could perform this extraction from two separate threads simultaneously.

The first thread extracts `libswt-gtk-4922r22.so` from ZIP archive, and `dlopen`s it. `dlopen` `mmap`s the file, relocates it, and invokes library initializer.

While the library initializer is running, a second thread decides that the library must be extracted (that's the bug), and truncates the `.so` file before writing new (identical) contents into it. As soon as truncate completes, the first thread (still running library initializer) gets killed with `SIGBUS`.

The usual fix is to make sure that "check that the file exists, extract if not" is done in a critical section.

Comment: Thanks, that's almost exactly what happened. I fixed the bug yesterday, but you was faster to post an answer :)  The only difference is that it was caused by starting two processes quickly. First seen that library is missing, started extracting it, second seen partial library on disk, loaded it and crashed. Critical sections can't help there, but I solved the problem by extracting into temporary file and moving it when it's fully written.